# How can i get , edit , update cart from Magento integrated Mobile Application?

Tags: magento

We are creating Mobile app which are integrated through magento website using our custom webservices module. We want when product is added to cart on desktop website that will also show in our mobile app. We can't access checkout/session in our mobile. Is there is any option to get Session Id from Customer Id. How this thing is implemented. Please Help.